# Django profiling tests

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

So I found [this](https://hackernoon.com/timing-tests-in-python-for-fun-and-profit-1663144571) article from 2016 detailing how to create a custom test runner that captures the time it takes to run tests in Django:

runner.py:

```
from unittest.runner import TextTestResult
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

import time

class TimeLoggingTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def __init__(self, slow_test_threshold=0.0, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slow_test_threshold = slow_test_threshold
        return super().__init__(
            resultclass=TimeLoggingTestResult,
            *args,
            **kwargs,
        )
    def run(self, test):
        result = super().run(test)
        self.stream.writeln(
            "\nSlow Tests (>{:.03}s):".format(
                self.slow_test_threshold))
        for name, elapsed in result.getTestTimings():
            if elapsed > self.slow_test_threshold:
                self.stream.writeln(
                    "({:.03}s) {}".format(
                        elapsed, name))
        return result

    def get_resultclass(self):
        return TimeLoggingTestResult

class TimeLoggingTestResult(TextTestResult):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.test_timings = []
    def startTest(self, test):
        self._test_started_at = time.time()
        super().startTest(test)
    def addSuccess(self, test):
        elapsed = time.time() - self._test_started_at
        name = self.getDescription(test)
        self.test_timings.append((name, elapsed))
        super().addSuccess(test)
    def getTestTimings(self):
        return self.test_timings
```

settings.py:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'core.utils.test_runner.runner.TimeLoggingTestRunner'
```

However, nothing prints at the end. I know the code runs, because debug statements fire in both classes - but the actual end result (`run`) doesn't appear to get called.

What I have managed to do is get the timings to print (by adding print statements inside `TimeLoggingTestResult`), but I can't seem to get them to all print out at the end.

Does anyone have any experience with doing something like this? The `run` method doesn't appear to be accessed at all.

Using Django 1.11.

Comment: I don't understand all your problem ( i'm not a django master) . But i created my own test_runner too, few days ago, and I am overriding `run_tests` method and not `run`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the docs, but `run_tests` works differently, and I'm not sure how to get it to work with this code.

Comment: You're right, there is a `run` method in [DiscoverRunner](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/runner.py#LC569).  Could you print what happen if you run tests with this runner but removing your own `run` method ?

Comment: So the tests run (because I get output from `TimeLoggingTestResult`) but I can't get the final result to print out.

Comment: I mean without overriding method  ̀run` ? And also i don't understand what's missing in your output.

Comment: If I remove run nothing gets printed, but I need run - because that's where my output should be printed from. If you look in the article you can see what the result should look like, but I don't see anything.

Comment: Try to add another`self.stream.writeln()` (with empty parameter) after your `self.stream.writeln("\nSlow Tests (>{:.0")`

Comment: It doesn't matter what's inside `run`, the function never gets called.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it looking for a way to profile my tests and tried to implement it myself. I'm on Django 3.0.8 but had the same issue as the Asker.

After looking into it, I found that `DiscoverRunner` does not inherit from TextTestRunner, it uses composition. Instead of calling `self.run()` it calls `runner.run()`. See code below.

```py
class DiscoverRunner:
    ...
    test_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner
    ...
    def run_suite(self, suite, **kwargs):
        kwargs = self.get_test_runner_kwargs()
        runner = self.test_runner(**kwargs)
        return runner.run(suite)
```

What I did was to make `TimeLoggingTestRunner` inherit both DiscoverRunner and TextTestRunner and overriding `run_suite()`.

```py
class TimeLoggingTestRunner(DiscoverRunner, TextTestRunner):
    def __init__(self, *args, slow_test_threshold=0.0, **kwargs):
        self.slow_test_threshold = slow_test_threshold
        DiscoverRunner.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        TextTestRunner.__init__(self, *args, **self.get_test_runner_kwargs())
    [...]
    def run_suite(self, suite, **kwargs):
        return self.run(suite)
```

There's probably better ways to deal with the inheritance, but it's working.

Another option might be to create two TestRunners, inheriting DiscoverRunner and TextTestRunner separately, and then composing them the same way DiscoverRunner does.